# Assign an imported function as a class method?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to assign an imported function as a class method, so that it automatically goes on an objects prototype chain?

```
// Module
module.exports = function testMethod() {
    console.log('From test method')
}

// Main
const testMethod = require('./testMethod')

class TestClass {
    // Replace this method with imported function
    testMethod() {
        console.log('From test method')
    }
}

const obj = new TestClass()
```

I was able to attach the method in this `constructor` using `this.testMethod = testMethod` but the method did not go on an objects prototype chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign to the `.prototype` property of the `TestClass` so that instances of `TestClass` will see the imported method:

```
class TestClass {
}
TestClass.prototype.testMethod = testMethod;
```

```js
const testMethod = () => console.log('test method');

class TestClass {
}
TestClass.prototype.testMethod = testMethod;

const tc = new TestClass();
tc.testMethod();
```

Comment: How about `static testMethod = testMethod;` inside the class body?